# WPF TreeView selecting next or previous items in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I would like to have previous/next arrows to select items in the treeview. I have 3 parent nodes that have childs. The parent nodes won't do anything so if I was at the end of the childs in parent node 1, I want the next arrow to select the 1st child in parent node 1. Same with the reverse if on the fist node of parent 2 and clicking previous will take me to the last child or parent node 1.

xaml of the treeview currently

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvMessages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="363" Margin="10,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312" SelectedItemChanged="tvMessages_SelectedItemChanged">
                <TreeViewItem x:Name="itemsCritical">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/FlashSystem/Images/Critical.png" Height="16px" Width="16px"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="Critical"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="/FlashSystem/Images/Message.png" Width="16px" Height="16px"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Specility}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssuedDate}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Severity}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem x:Name="itemsAlert">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/FlashSystem/Images/Alert.png" Height="16px" Width="16px"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="Alert"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="/FlashSystem/Images/Message.png" Width="16px" Height="16px"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Specility}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssuedDate}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Severity}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem x:Name="itemsInformational">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/FlashSystem/Images/Info.png" Height="16px" Width="16px"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="Informational"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="/FlashSystem/Images/Message.png" Width="16px" Height="16px"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Specility}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssuedDate}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Severity}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeView>
```

Comment: That behavior is already happening in TreeView assuming all node are collapsed. If you hit right arrow once a root node will be expanded. If you hit the right arrow one more time the first node of root node will be selected. Futhermore if you again hit the right arrow the first node of root node will be expanded. That is how right/left arrow work in TreeView. One time they expand another time they select next... Expand, select next, expand, select next...

Comment: I want to use actual buttons on the window to control it rather then the arrow keys

Comment: I see now you were talking about buttons with arrows and I ment the keyboard arrows. Let me post you an answer. Comments allow limited numbers of characters...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to simulate the key down event and see if it works.

If you simulate the arrow key down event the TreeViewItem will do the job for you. It will either expand itself or move the selection to its Children[0] item.

Internally TreeViewItem listens to KeyDown and it works with ItemContainerGenerator to find the Children[0] item.

Here is how you can simulate arrow key in WPF:

```
var backKey = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Back);  
backKey.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;  
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(backKey);
```

You wont need the back key you will need the right or left arrow still you will need InputManager to process input :)